# can't compile document that calls graphicx

Tags: graphics

I'm getting an error message when I compile several documents.  If I comment out `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\includegraphics` the document compiles fine (without the image, of course).

I'm particularly flummoxed because one of the files exhibiting the problem is one I've updated annually for the last 6 years or so, and all has been well until last week.

The error message I'm getting is

`! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.1 ... f={};f.navigateTo=function(b,a,g){if(b!=a&
                                                  &b.google){if(b.google.r){...`

This is an example of the code producing the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent = 0 in

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

    \item \label{map} Draw a graph that represents this map.  Discuss decisions you made in coming up with the graph.

\includegraphics[scale=.7]{map_1.JPG}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any useful suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

As seen here

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31215/google-search-results-are-invalid

the javascript code that you show is part of the html wrapper page that google puts around search results, so one of the files being input is not a tex file but an html page.

Your log file will show which file is corrupt, but you have not shown that information so we have to guess, also if it is in the preamble it is hard to see how this can be the first error and you do not get a "missing `\begin{document}`" error first?

For example if `pdftex.def` looks like

```
... f={};f.navigateTo=function(b,a,g){if(b!=a&&b.google){if(b.google.r){.
```

Then the file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

will produce the terminal output

```
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> pre-release-6
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(./pdftex.def

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 .
     .. f={};f.navigateTo=function(b,a,g){if(b!=a&&b.google){if(b.google.r){.
? 
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.1 ... f={};f.navigateTo=function(b,a,g){if(b!=a&
                                                  &b.google){if(b.google.r){.
?
```

Note that this is the *second* error (errors after the first are often spurious) and the `(./pdftex.def` before the error shows which file the problem is in.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, David.  I think that the problem is not likely to be in the jpeg file.  The image displays correctly if I use it in another document.  Similarly, if I replace `map_1.JPG` with a different jpeg file, which displays correctly in another document, I still get the same error message when compiling the example above.  In fact, if I comment out the `\includegraphics` command, but do not comment out the `\usepackage{graphicx}` command, I still get the same error message.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Martha well... two comments, your log file shows which file is causing the problem but you have not shown that information, so we have to guess, and secondly a "minimal working example" is supposed to be the minimal needed to generate the error, so if you don't need `\includegraphics` it shouldn't have been in the example, and then I would have made a different guess....  I updated the answer